# Render some HTML tag from another web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, rest

I want to render some value of span element from internal website to my website by GET / FETCH request or by another alternative.

This is my current code but actually IDK what to do, I've managed to receive some un-useful data and not the data I need, and even this data was the expected data, I want to render only the span value from there.

```
async function uiTagChecking() {
    $.ajax({
        url:  url,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            const curSpan = document.getElementById(data);
        }

    });
}
```

**Technical info:**

Node JS

JavaScript

HTML + CSS

Answer (score -1):

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    const curSpan = document.getElementById(data);
    curSpan.innerHTML = data;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't define innerHTML. 
but anyway it doesn't print the expected source I want to.. the version tag is missed from this data, i need the real source of the page i trying to GET by the request

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, I was out of touch. Can you share your html part where you want to set the data & also `console.log(data)` in the question?